# Derivative of Weierstrass function

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

I need to prove the following:

$$\Omega = \mathbb{Z}\omega +\mathbb{Z}\omega':  $$

$$ \wp'(z)= \frac{\sigma(z-\frac{\omega}{2})\sigma(z-\frac{\omega'}{2}) \sigma(z+\frac{\eta}{2})}{\sigma(z)^{3}\sigma(\frac{\omega}{2})\sigma(\frac{\omega'}{2})\sigma(-\frac{\eta}{2})} $$

where $\eta = \omega + \omega'$ and $\wp$ is the Weierstrass p function

I know the following facts:

$$ \zeta(z)= \frac{\sigma'(z)}{\sigma(z)} $$

$$ = \frac{1}{z} + \Sigma_{\omega \in \Omega} (\frac{1}{z-\omega}+\frac{1}{\omega}+\frac{z}{\omega^{2}}) $$

and

$$ \wp'(z) = -\frac{2}{z^{3}}- \Sigma'_{\omega \in \Omega} \frac{2}{(z-\omega)^{3}} $$

But, how do I get from here to what I want to prove?

Comment: Have you tried taking logarithmic derivatives first?

Comment: You should look at the zeros and poles of $\,\wp'(z)\,$ and compare it to the $\,\sigma\,$ quotient.